# _NXTermWindow: error releasing window (1001)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous

This isn't an extremely important issue, but I am curious as to why it's happening. Basically, I open an `NSSharingService` window with the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Get the sharable items from a custom method
    NSArray *shareItems = self.sharableItems;

    // Pick service dependent on type sent via JS
    NSSharingService *service;
    if ([shareType isEqualToString:@"Messages"]){
        service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage];
    } else if ([shareType isEqualToString:@"Email"]){
        service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
    } else if ([shareType isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]){
        service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook];
    } else if ([shareType isEqualToString:@"Twitter"]){
        service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter];
    }
    service.delegate = self;

    // Update the UI in the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [service performWithItems:shareItems];
    });
});
```

The `NSSharingService` window opens properly, but when I either "send" or "cancel" sending the message, the console outputs:

> _NXTermWindow: error releasing window (1001)

[Google produced no helpful results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22_NXTermWindow%3a%20error%20releasing%20window%20%281001%29%22&rls=en). It might be worth noting that I have the following related methods implemented:

```
- (NSWindow *)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService sourceWindowForShareItems:(NSArray *)items sharingContentScope:(NSSharingContentScope *)sharingContentScope{
    return self.window;
}

- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didShareItems:(NSArray *)items;

- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didFailToShareItems:(NSArray *)items error:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Hello, Charlie.  Have you found out what's wrong?  I see the same warning with NSSharingService.  If I play with Apple's sample project, I get the same message only if I sandbox it.  So it seems that there's nothing to worry about because you get a similar warning message when you invoke NSOpenPanel, which only happens if the application is sandboxed.

Comment: @ElTomato I never did find out what was wrong.